# Convert raw_input’s output to integer

Tags: python

```
def total():
    n = prompt()
    answer = (n-2)*180
    print ("The polygon has", answer, "sides.")

 def prompt():
     x = raw_input("Type number: ")
     return x
```

I'm trying to get `n` which is equal to the output of `prompt` to be an integer so that math can be done on it. How would I do this?

Comment: `n = int(prompt())`, or `return int(x)` (depending on where you want the conversion to happen)

Answer (score 0):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, so you cannot use it for any calculations. If you want to have an integer instead, you can use the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function to convert the value. You can do that either within your `prompt` function, or later in the calling function (although it would make more sense to have a function that asks the user for a number return one):

```
def prompt ():
    x = raw_input("Type a number: ")
    return int(x)
```

Note, that `int()` may raise a `ValueError` for any user entered value that is not a valid integer. In that case, you should catch the exception and prompt the user again to correct the input. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) on how that would work.